# How to install and enable php ext-exif on github codespace/linux

Tags: php, linux, laravel, codespaces

I am trying to install `spatie/media-library` on a Laravel project on codespace.
it works on my local machine but in codespace, it says `ext-exif` not found.
how can I install it on codespace?

I have instantiated a codespace using the default image
`{"image":"mcr.microsoft.com/devcontainers/universal:2"}`

the image does not contain the php `ext-exif`.

I have tried to enable the extension from `php.ini`. it says `exif.so` not found in extension directories.

Answer (score -1):

have you tried this command?

`sudo apt install php-exif`

after that, you can check installed extensions using:

`php -m`

Comment: This image doesn't use apt for PHP, so `apt install php-exif` doesn't work. Did you try your suggested answer? You'll notice that in this image the different PHP versions are installed in `/usr/local/php/`.

Comment: so you can use **Pecl**

`pecl install exif`

or try: `docker-php-ext-install exif`